# Convert Loop in Microsoft SQL Server to Set-Based Logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a loop that is taking a long time to run in 2016 Microsoft SQL Server. I know that SQL is much better at performing set-based operations but I am having a hard time implementing that type of solution in my case.

Essentially I have 2 tables that look like this to begin:

`#TEMP`

```
| OVERALL RN | HQ RN | BRANCH RN | ID |  BRANCH EMP | HQ CHARACTERISTICS    | FLAG |
|------------|-------|-----------|----|-------------|-----------------------|------|
| 1          |   100 |    1      | 50 | 25          |100-125 EMP, CALIFORNIA| NULL |
| 2          |   100 |    2      | 60 | 50          |100-125 EMP, CALIFORNIA| NULL |
| 3          |   100 |    3      | 70 | 80          |100-125 EMP, CALIFORNIA| NULL |
| 4          |   150 |    1      | 70 | 80          |200-225 EMP, TEXAS     | NULL |
| 5          |   150 |    2      | 56 | 70          |200-225 EMP, TEXAS     | NULL |
| 6          |   600 |    1      | 56 | 70          |500-600 EMP, ARIZONA   | NULL |
| 7          |   663 |    1      | 52 | 79          |200-225 EMP, TEXAS     | NULL |
```

`#MAX_MIN_EMPLOYMENT`

```
| HQ CHARACTERISTICS     | CURRENT EMP | EMP LOWER BOUND | EMP UPPER BOUND| MIN EMP BRANCH | MAX EMP BRANCH | BRANCH REMAINING |
|------------------------|-------------|-----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|------------------|
| 100-125 EMP, CALIFORNIA| 50          | 100             | 125            | 50             | 75             | 1                |
| 200-225 EMP, TEXAS     | 75          | 200             | 225            | 62.5           | 75             | 2                |
| 500-600 EMP, ARIZONA   | 450         | 500             | 600            | 50             | 150            | 1                |
```

The overall goal is to match each unique `HQ RN` to an `ID`. Each `ID` can only be used once just as each `HQ RN` can only be used once. You can see in the table `#TEMP` there are many different options for each `HQ RN` - for instance `HQ RN` = 100 can be matched to 3 possible branches, `ID` = 50, 60, or 70 - each with different employment values. However, it can only pair with 1 of these options (or none).

The table `#MAX_MIN_EMPLOYMENT` joins on the table `#TEMP` through the `HQ CHARACTERISTICS` column and tells us how many branches can still be added (`BRANCH REMAINING`) and also provides us with details on how large the branch can be (`MIN EMP BRANCH` and `MAX EMP BRANCH`). If we look at `OVERALL RN` = 1 in `#TEMP` we see that the `BRANCH EMP` = 25 which is not between the `MIN EMP BRANCH` and `MAX EMP BRANCH`. Thus, we can set `FLAG` = X and `HQ RN` = 100 cannot be paired with `ID` = 50.

Ultimately, what we want is a final table that looks like this:

`FINAL_TABLE`

```
 | OVERALL RN | HQ RN | ID |
 |------------|-------|----|
 | 2          | 100   | 60 |
 | 5          | 150   | 56 |
 | 7          | 663   | 52 |
```

Here is what ends up happening and what the tables look like at the end:

- `OVERALL RN` = 1 is flagged because `BRANCH EMP` is too small.
- `OVERALL RN` = 2 - `HQ RN` = 100 is assigned to `ID` = 60 because the `BRANCH EMP` is between `MIN BRANCH EMP` and `MAX BRANCH EMP`.
- `OVERALL RN` = 3 is flagged because we already assigned `HQ RN` = 100 to an `ID`.
- `OVERALL RN` = 4 is flagged because `BRANCH EMP` is too large.
- `OVERALL RN` = 5 - `HQ RN` = 150 is assigned to `ID` = 56 because the `BRANCH EMP` is between `MIN BRANCH EMP` and `MAX BRANCH EMP`.
- `OVERALL RN` = 6 is flagged because the `ID` = 56 was already used.
- `OVERALL RN` = 7 is not flagged due to the `BRANCH EMP` being too high because the `MIN EMP BRANCH` and `MAX EMP BRANCH` were re-computed for `HQ CHARACTERISTICS` = 200-225 EMP, TEXAS after `OVERALL RN` = 5 was determined to be a good match. `HQ RN` = 663 is assigned to `ID` = 52 because the `BRANCH EMP` is between `MIN BRANCH EMP` and `MAX BRANCH EMP`.

`#TEMP`

```
| OVERALL RN | HQ RN | BRANCH RN | ID |  BRANCH EMP | HQ CHARACTERISTICS    | FLAG |
|------------|-------|-----------|----|-------------|-----------------------|------|
| 1          |   100 |    1      | 50 | 25          |100-125 EMP, CALIFORNIA| X    |
| 2          |   100 |    2      | 60 | 50          |100-125 EMP, CALIFORNIA| NULL |
| 3          |   100 |    3      | 70 | 80          |100-125 EMP, CALIFORNIA| X    |
| 4          |   150 |    1      | 70 | 80          |200-225 EMP, TEXAS     | X    |
| 5          |   150 |    2      | 56 | 70          |200-225 EMP, TEXAS     | NULL |
| 6          |   600 |    1      | 56 | 70          |500-600 EMP, ARIZONA   | X    |
| 7          |   663 |    1      | 52 | 79          |200-225 EMP, TEXAS     | NULL |
```

`#MAX_MIN_EMPLOYMENT`

```
| HQ CHARACTERISTICS     | CURRENT EMP | EMP LOWER BOUND | EMP UPPER BOUND| MIN EMP BRANCH | MAX EMP BRANCH | BRANCH REMAINING |
|------------------------|-------------|-----------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|------------------|
| 100-125 EMP, CALIFORNIA| 100         | 100             | 125            | 0              | 25             | 0                |
| 200-225 EMP, TEXAS     | 224         | 200             | 225            | 0              | 1              | 0                |
| 500-600 EMP, ARIZONA   | 450         | 500             | 600            | 50             | 150            | 1                |
```

My procedure, as currently written, loops over the `OVERALL RN` variable and updates `#TEMP` and `#MAX_MIN_EMPLOYMENT` after each row. Is there any way to turn this into set-based logic?

Many thanks!

## Edit - Added Sample Code:

```
DECLARE @RN_BEGIN_ID INT
DECLARE @RN_END_ID INT

SET @RN_BEGIN_ID = 1
SELECT @RN_END_ID = MAX([OVERALL_RN]) FROM #TEMP 

WHILE @RN_BEGIN_ID <= @RN_END_ID

BEGIN

UPDATE #TEMP 
SET [FLAG] = 'X'

FROM 

#TEMP A

INNER JOIN

#MAX_MIN_EMPLOYMENT B

ON A.[HQ_CHARACTERISTICS] = B.[HQ_CHARACTERISTICS]

WHERE (A.[EMPLOYMENT_BRANCH] < B.[MIN_EMPLOYMENT_BRANCH] OR A.[EMPLOYMENT_BRANCH] > B.[MAX_EMPLOYMENT_BRANCH]) AND A.[FLAG] IS NULL

------------------------------------------------

--FINALIZE RESULTS

INSERT INTO #FINAL_TABLE
SELECT
[OVERALL_RN],
[HQ_CHARACTERISTICS],
[HQ_RN],
[ID]
FROM #TEMP
WHERE [OVERALL_RN] = @RN_BEGIN_ID AND [FLAG] IS NULL

------------------------------------------------

--UPDATE MIN/MAX EMPLOYMENT PER BRANCH

UPDATE #MAX_MIN_EMPLOYMENT
SET
[EMPLOYMENT_CURRENT] = A.[EMPLOYMENT_CURRENT] + B.[EMPLOYMENT_BRANCH],
[BRANCH_REMAINING] = A.[BRANCH_REMAINING] - 1

FROM 

#MAX_MIN_EMPLOYMENT A

INNER JOIN

#FINAL_TABLE B

ON A.[HQ_CHARACTERISTICS] = B.[HQ_CHARACTERISTICS]

WHERE B.[OVERALL_RN] = @RN_BEGIN_ID

------------------------------------------------

DELETE D FROM #MAX_MIN_EMPLOYMENT D WHERE [BRANCH_REMAINING] = 0

------------------------------------------------

UPDATE #MAX_MIN_EMPLOYMENT
SET
[MIN_EMPLOYMENT_BRANCH] = CASE WHEN [EMPLOYMENT_CURRENT] >= [LOWER_BOUND] THEN 0 ELSE ((CAST([LOWER_BOUND] AS FLOAT) - [EMPLOYMENT_CURRENT])/[BRANCH_REMAINING]) END, 
[MAX_EMPLOYMENT_BRANCH] = CASE WHEN [EMPLOYMENT_CURRENT] >= [UPPER_BOUND] THEN 0 ELSE ((CAST([UPPER_BOUND] AS FLOAT) - [EMPLOYMENT_CURRENT])/[BRANCH_REMAINING]) END 
FROM #MAX_MIN_EMPLOYMENT

------------------------------------------------

--MAKE SURE ID'S GET ELIMINATED ONCE USED

UPDATE #TEMP
SET [FLAG] = 'X'

FROM

#TEMP A

INNER JOIN

(SELECT [ID] FROM #FINAL_TABLE WHERE [OVERALL_RN] = @RN_BEGIN_ID) B

ON A.[ID] = B.[ID]

WHERE A.[OVERALL_RN] > @RN_BEGIN_ID AND [FLAG] IS NULL

------------------------------------------------

--MAKE SURE HQ_RN'S GET ELIMINATED ONCE USED

UPDATE #TEMP
SET [FLAG] = 'X'

FROM

#TEMP A

INNER JOIN

(SELECT [HQ_RN] FROM #FINAL_TABLE WHERE [OVERALL_RN] = @RN_BEGIN_ID) B

ON A.[HQ_RN] = B.[HQ_RN]

WHERE A.[OVERALL_RN] > @RN_BEGIN_ID AND [FLAG] IS NULL

------------------------------------------------

SET @RN_BEGIN_ID = @RN_BEGIN_ID + 1

END
```

Comment: Yes this could very likely be changed to use set based logic. What would really help though is to see the ddl and sample data for your tables. Also the existing code you have that works would be good. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Is the link between the two tables `Branch RN` and `Branch Remaining`?

Comment: I'll post sample code momentarily. The only link between `#TEMP` and `#MAX_MIN_EMP` is `HQ CHARACTERISTICS`. `BRANCH RN` is a row number operation that partitions on `HQ RN` and orders by `ID`.

Comment: Read Jeff Moden's [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I read through the article. It appears to be different because in their example the "tally table" is untouched and does not get updated at all

Comment: @SeanLange any suggestions? I added the existing code that was being used.

Comment: This makes no sense to me at all. You seem to have quite a bit of business logic going on here but the explanation is nearly non-existent. Providing ddl and sample data in a consumable format would go a LONG way to helping here. Think create table and insert statements.

Comment: The tally table should not be updated, it should be used instead of a loop. I'll see if I can create an example for you later today.